# Laravel auto-injection issue (Too few arguments) after migrating to PHP 8.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8.2

I recently migrated my Laravel project to PHP 8.1, and I'm encountering an issue with dependency injection in my controllers. I have set up auto-injection in my AppServiceProvider using the bind method, but I'm getting a "Too few arguments" error in my controller methods.

Here's the relevant part of my AppServiceProvider:

```
use App\Repositories\TenantRepository;
use App\Repositories\AdministrationRepository;
use App\Repositories\TenantRepositoryInterface;
use App\Repositories\AdministrationRepositoryInterface;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(TenantRepositoryInterface::class, TenantRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind(AdministrationRepositoryInterface::class, AdministrationRepository::class);
    }
}
```

And here's a sample controller method:

```
use App\Repositories\TenantRepositoryInterface;
use App\Repositories\AdministrationRepositoryInterface;

class [ControllerName] extends Controller
{
    public function tenantListe($message = "", $niveauMessage = "", TenantRepositoryInterface $interface)
    {
        // Method implementation...
    }

    // Other controller methods...
}
```

I have multiple controller methods, each using a different repository interface. Before the migration, this setup was working fine.

How can I resolve this "Too few arguments" error and properly set up dependency injection in my Laravel controller methods after migrating to PHP 8.1?

After encountering the "Too few arguments" issue in my Laravel controllers post-migration to PHP 8.1, I tried reorganizing the parameters by placing TenantRepositoryInterface $interface as the first parameter in the method signature. For example:

```
public function tenantListe(TenantRepositoryInterface $interface, $message = "", $niveauMessage = "")
```

This adjustment resolved the problem for this specific method. However, considering the large number of methods in my project, manually reorganizing each method is not a scalable solution.

Is there a more efficient and automated way to address this issue across all my controller methods, considering the recent migration to PHP 8.1?

Comment: If I am not confused, the order does not matter at all, as what Laravel does is look on each parameter, if it can be resolved by type or it already has a default value, it goes to the next parameter. In this case, it finds the type and is able to resolve it. Related to the order, what I have in mind is that you do not have `string` defined for the other types. Try having the original order, but on this one, just add `string` (or the right type) to the previous parameters and see if that worked. Also, please do share the full error log

Comment: Add a linter (PHPStan or Psalm, for example) to your project. They would have told you long ago that non-optional arguments following optional arguments are bad. Psalm (not sure about PHPStan) also has the ability to fix some issues it finds automatically.